# Ghostable and Unghostable Pages

Tags: ghosting, viewstate, unghosting

What are `Ghostable` and `Unghostable` Pages? Is there a `list`of pages which are Ghostable and Unghostable? How would I know whether a page is Ghostable or unghostable? If we just add a document to a Ghostable Page, will it be called as Unghostable?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/understanding-ghosting-unghosting-site-pages-and-application-pages

Comment: Dear @TusharAnand regarding your query about it's duplicate I think it's should be within comments also Nadeem set the similar link that the moderator talks about it ,you can check it ,

Comment: yea, saw the link.

Comment: Is it like every default home page is Ghosted page?

Comment: yes as I answered below

Comment: How this is even a duplicate of "How to check if a page is ghosted "?? He is asking **what Ghosting/Unghosting is** in the first place and only as a side question he is asking if there is a way to list which page is what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ghosted pages (unCustomized)**: the Pages that stored on `File System` like

- Application Pages.
- The default home page
- Site Definition pages.

**Unghosted pages (Customized)** : the pages that stored in `SharePoint Content Database`

- SitePages like [Add/display/edit].
- Custom Master Pages.

Note : All the Unghosted sites are based on Ghosted Site Definition.

Check also [What is the concept of ghosting and un-ghosting in SharePoint?](http://www.codedigest.com/FAQ/11-What-is-the-concept-of-ghosting-and-unghosting-in-SharePoint-.aspx)

Check Also [Understanding ghosting, unghosting, site pages and application pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/understanding-ghosting-unghosting-site-pages-and-application-pages)